# 'AutoMapper.Configuration' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: unity-container, automapper, ioc-container, automapper-3

I am trying to upgrade AutoMapper  1.1 to AutoMapper 3.3. I have the following statement in my current code that does not work in v3.3

```
container.RegisterType<IConfiguration, global::AutoMapper.Configuration>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

container is a Unity container. I am getting the following error.

> 'AutoMapper.Configuration' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

How do i change this statement to work with AutoMapper 3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that AutoMapper.Configuration is changed to

> AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore

The following line works.

```
container.RegisterType<IConfiguration, global::AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```